# How to get a specific value using RecursiveIteratorIterator

Tags: php, arrays, iterator

I want to get a specific value  of multidimensional array   using RecursiveIteratorIterator

I want to get it like normal loop if possible

$val['key'];

my code

```
$data = array(
    'title' =>'how to work',
    'posts' => array(
        array(
            'title' => 'introduction to iterators',
            'email' => 'kingahmadz@hotmail.com'
        ),
        array(
            'title' => 'introduction to iterators2',
            'email' => 'kingahmadz@hotmail.com'
        ),
        array(
            'title' => 'introduction to iterators3',
            'email' => 'kingahmadz@hotmail.com'
        ),
    ));


foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($data)) as $item => $val) {
  echo $val['email'];
}
```

Comment: So when you flatten the array in this way and do `$val['title'];` or `$val['email'];`, what would you expect it to display? You have several array values with the same index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to get all emails only you should use [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php):

```
$posts = $data['posts'];

foreach (array_column($posts, 'email') as $email) {
    echo $email, PHP_EOL;
}
```

However, **if you need to get all emails values regardless of depth you have several options**.

#### Use simple [`RecursiveIteratorIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php):

```
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveArrayIterator($data)
);

foreach ($iterator as $key => $value) {
    if ($key === 'email') {
        echo $value, PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

#### Use [`RecursiveCallbackFilterIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivecallbackfilteriterator.php) or [`RecursiveFilterIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivefilteriterator.php):

```
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveCallbackFilterIterator(
        new RecursiveArrayIterator($data), 
        function ($_, $key, $iterator) {
            if($iterator->hasChildren()) {
                return true;
            }

            return $key === 'email'; 
        }
    )
);

foreach ($iterator as $email) {
    echo $email, PHP_EOL;
}
```

#### Use [`RecursiveRegexIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveregexiterator.php):

```
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveRegexIterator(
        new RecursiveArrayIterator($data),
        '/^email$/',
        RegexIterator::MATCH,
        RegexIterator::USE_KEY
    )
);

foreach ($iterator as $email) {
    echo $email, PHP_EOL;   
}
```

Here is [working demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/57d99fa7eb8e4f4ad4947a5984adabbda7810690).

Answer (score 1):

Actually, using `RecursiveIteratorIterator` object would be overcomplicated and non-optimal for such simple case.
If it's just for test use the following approach:

```
$key = 'email';
$it = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator(new \RecursiveArrayIterator($data), \RecursiveIteratorIterator::CATCH_GET_CHILD);
$emails = array_column($it->getInnerIterator()['posts'], $key);

print_r($emails);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => kingahmadz@hotmail.com
    [1] => kingahmadz@hotmail.com
    [2] => kingahmadz@hotmail.com
)
```

---

It's even simpler without using Iterators and applying `array_column` function at once to get same result:

```
$emails = array_column($data['posts'], $key);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, `$item` is the key and `$val` is the value. If you want to output a specific key, then you can do the following:

```
foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($data)) as $item => $val) {
    if ($item == 'email') {
        echo $val . '<br />';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi can you explaine why do you need to use RecursiveIteratorIterator Because in your exemple you can use array_column to get The Email

```
array_column($data['posts'], 'email')
```